# Cassandra multinode cluster setup issue (for example 3 nodes)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am keep getting below error when I tried to run single node or multinode Cassandra cluster.

Single node cluster with default config works fine, however nodetool staus shows 127.0.0.1 as IP Address.

After changing listen_address: 192.168.1.143 (this is my ip address) on cassandra.yaml file I am getting below error.

```
Exception (java.lang.RuntimeException) encountered during startup: Unable to gossip with any peers
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any peers
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1443)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.checkForEndpointCollision(StorageService.java:547)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:804)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:664)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:613)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:379)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:602)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:691)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after trying different approaches finally I was able to resolve it and able to run single and 3 node cluster.

Below are the configuration changes you need to make on cassandra.yaml file

```
First Node
--------------
listen_address: 192.168.1.143 (This should be your server/node IP)
seeds: "192.168.1.143" (For your first node please mention your node IP address)

Second Node
---------------
listen_address: 192.168.1.144 (This should be your server/node IP)
seeds: "192.168.1.143" (specify your first node IP, additionally, you can also mention current IP address ,192.168.1.144)

Third Node
---------------
listen_address: 192.168.1.145 (This should be your server/node IP)
seeds: "192.168.1.143" (specify your first/second node IP, additionally, you can also mention current IP address ,192.168.1.145)
```

After starting cassandra on all 3 servers, nodetool status returned the following

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.143  258.83 KiB  256          100.0%            7b3a0644-c8dd-4a47-9186-0237f3725941  rack1
UN  192.168.1.144  309.71 KiB  256          100.0%            e7a11a60-d795-47ee-8d21-7cc21b4cbdca  rack1
UN  192.168.1.145  309.71 KiB  256          100.0%            b2a4545a-f279-r5h7-2fy6-23dk8fg5c8kq  rack1
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for joining cassandra cluster first time. you should start seed node first then other nodes.